Integrating ERC20 Approval Before Transaction using Wagmi on Frontend
I have a dapp where users send erc20 tokens to the smart contract, obviously requiring the user to approve the smart contract to transfer tokens on their behalf.
On the frontend of my app, when someone presses a button, I want to prompt an erc20 approval for the user and then if the approval succeeds, I want to prompt the user to sign a transaction calling the smart contract function that then transfers the tokens.
I have the following code for a function within a function component attempting to send an approval request to the user (which happens properly by a Metamask pop-up appearing), but most of the time the following sendToken transaction does not show up in a Metamask popup afterwards.
I have noticed that upon pressing the button in my code which runs this 'submit' function, the text 'approving token transfer' is printed to console, then 'sending token' is printed to console immediately afterwards. The text 'sending token' is printed regardless of if I have completed the first metamask approval transaction, which is not what I want to happen. I don't want execution of the function to reach the console.log('sending token') line until the token approval is complete.
How can I do this correctly so that the transaction metamask popup always appears after the ERC20 metamask approval? (I am using wagmi hooks on my vercel frontend).
async function submit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (!receiverAddress) {
      alert('Please connect your wallet.');
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement)
    const asset = formData.get('asset') as string
    const amount_wei = formData.get('amount_wei') as string
    const targetAddress: `0x${string}` = formData.get('target_address') as `0x${string}`;
    const secret = formData.get('secret') as string

    let token_address = "";
    if (asset === 'USDT') {
      token_address = "0xaA8E23Fb1079EA71e0a56F48a2aA51851D8433D0";
    } else if (asset === 'USDC') {
      token_address = "0xf08A50178dfcDe18524640EA6618a1f965821715";
    } else if (asset === 'LINK') {
      token_address = "0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789";
    } else if (asset === 'UNI') {
      token_address = "0x41952a7F9247442292410EEa5CC94a0Be3724399";
    }

    // Convert amount_wei to BigInt or BigNumber
    const amountWeiBigInt = BigInt(amount_wei);

    if (asset === 'eth') {
      console.log('sending eth');
      writeContract({
        address: smartContractAddress,
        abi,
        functionName: 'sendEth',
        args: [targetAddress, secret],//need to also add payable amount
        value: amountWeiBigInt, // Use amountWeiBN if using BigNumber
      })
    } else {
      console.log('approving token transfer');
      const result = await writeContract({
          address: token_address,
          abi,
          functionName: 'approve',
          args: [smartContractAddress, amountWeiBigInt],//need to also add payable amount
      })

      

      console.log('sending token');
      const result2 = await writeContract({
        address: smartContractAddress,
        abi,
        functionName: 'sendToken',
        args: [targetAddress, amountWeiBigInt, secret, token_address],//need to also add payable amount
      })
    }
  }


Can you please specify any errors? or what exactly do you mean by "does not show up"? Are you talking about the metamask pop up? Also what is the problem with Approval as mentioned in the question title?

Sorry about that, I added more clarification to the post.

You can utilize the waitForTransactionReceipt function of @wagmi/core package.
But, in order to get the transaction hash to be passed, you need to import and use the writeContract function of the @wagmi/core directly, instead of importing the useWriteContract hook of wagmi and then using its writeContract function, because the return type of the former one is a Promise<String> and it returns the transaction hash, whereas the latter one is of type void.
So, your revised else block would be:
console.log('approving token transfer');
const result = await writeContract(config, {
    address: token_address,
    abi,
    functionName: 'approve',
    args: [smartContractAddress, amountWeiBigInt],
})

await waitForTransactionReceipt(
    config, {
    hash: result,
    confirmations: 1, // You can change the number of block confirmations as per your requirement
})

console.log('sending token');
const result2 = await writeContract(config, {
    address: smartContractAddress,
    abi,
    functionName: 'sendToken',
    args: [targetAddress, amountWeiBigInt, secret, token_address],
})

P.S., The config is imported from the wagmi.ts file, like:
import { config } from '../wagmi'

And, the writeContract and waitForTransactionReceipt functions are imported from @wagmi/core like:
import { writeContract, waitForTransactionReceipt } from '@wagmi/core'

